# Cybersource silent order with 3D secure

Tags: python, 3d-secure, cybersource

I have implemented cybersource silent order api. It is working in testing environment. But now I have to add the 3D secure also. I am not getting any help how to add this functionality. There documentation gives some information with simple order api only.

Comment: I am afraid that Silent Order API is actually meant for frontends to directly POST to Cybersource, but first you need to verify it is enabled: [Enable Payer Authentication](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_SOP/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=creating_profile.05.2.html) Can you hint to the motivation you cannot use Simple Order/SOAP ?

Answer (score 0):

3-D Secure (Payer Authentication) is supported by the Silent Order Post(SOP) method.

1. Payer Authentication must be enabled by CyberSource and is not enabled by default with a test account.
2. Payer Authentication must be enabled within your SOP profile for each card type you accept. This is done in the Enterprise Business Center. See the [documentation](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_SOP/Secure_Acceptance_SOP.pdf) "Enabling Payer Authentication" section.
3. Once that is done you can test payer authentication scenarios by using the card numbers mentioned in the payer authentication [documentation](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Payer_Authentication_SO_API/Payer_Authentication_SO_API.pdf) section "Testing Payer Authentication Services"